# Error says "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: c#, ms-access

Is there anything wrong with my codes? Because, I'm about to create a login form and it doesn't.

```
OleDbConnection conDataBase = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\tess\Documents\iknow.accdb;" + "Persist Security Info = True");
OleDbCommand cmdDataBase = new OleDbCommand(" select * from iknow where Username = '"+user_NameTextBox.Text+"'");
cmdDataBase.Connection = conDataBase;
OleDbDataReader myReader;

conDataBase.Open();
myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
int count = 0;
while (myReader.Read())
{
    count = count + 1;
}
if (count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username");
}
```

Comment: isnt there a possibility to have more than 1 rows returned?? In that case you should check on count>=1. Also very vital: BEWARE of SQL INJECTION

Comment: Well I would *start* with the SQL injection attack vulnerability from putting a user-supplied value directly into your SQL. **Always parameterize SQL.**

Comment: this post lacks a clear problem description. debug first, check if the while loop is ever entered, run the query manually in Access and check if it returns anything. and there is no entry specifically for Microsoft Access, but [this still applies](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues, as Jon Skeet pointed out you've introduced a SQL injection vulnerability, aren't implementing the `using` syntax to dispose of resources correctly, and have a parameter but aren't actually implementing (this is hard to identify, without more code or what flagged this error).

```
var query = "SELECT TOP 1 [Id] FROM User WHERE Username = @Username";
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(path))
using(var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
{
     connection.Open();
     command.Parameters("Username", txtUsername.Text());
     using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
          while(reader.Read())
          {
               // Do something.
          }
}
```

So the above code would address the following:

- Injection point
- Disposing resources
- Correctly associating command to connection
- No reason to * for everything, if you only want to see if it exists.
- You should really only have a single username, so TOP 1 could refine.

You also could use `ExecuteScalar` instead of reader, that way you can simply validate the record was returned.  This would alleviate the need to iterate through the returned record set.  If you TOP 1 and ensure only one username exists, won't matter but it is an option.

As for your parameter, we would need more information.  The debugger should tell you which line is throwing the exception.  Those details could help resolve the issue.

Comment: the debugger doesnot tell me which line is throwing the exception, it just shows a messagebox saying that no value given for one or more required parameters. but i will keep in mind the things that you said.